# Python/Pandas: Get index of item in a column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a Pandas dataframe(df) with following columns:

df["ids"]

```
0         18281483,1658391547
1           1268212,128064430
2                  1346542425
3  13591493,13123669,35938208
```

df["id"]

```
0      18281483
1       1268212
2    1346542425
3      13123669
```

I like to find out, in which order of "ids" the respective "id" can be found, and output the respective value in a new column "order". Following code was tried without success:

```
df["order"] = df["ids"].str.split(",").index(df["id"])

----------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError: 'Int64Index' object is not callable
```

Is there a syntax error? I tried the split and index function with every row manually (by inserting the lists and string), and it worked.

Desired output:

df["order"]

```
0 0
1 0
2 0 
3 1
```

Comment: What's the expected output for this data?

Comment: I want to have a column "order" that tells me in which index number the "id" appears in "ids". For instance, for row indices 0, 1 and 2 that would be "0" and for row 3 it would be "1", given indices start with 0. I added an example, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df['output'] = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x['ids'].split(',').index(x['id']), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                          ids          id  output
0         18281483,1658391547    18281483       0
1           1268212,128064430     1268212       0
2                  1346542425  1346542425       0
3  13591493,13123669,35938208    13123669       1
```

Comment: "ValueError: 18281483 is not in list". Same for you?

Comment: Looks like `id` column is integer. You can convert `df` to string as updated.

Comment: ´df.apply(lambda x: x['ids'].split(',').index(str(x['id'])), axis=1)´ works indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a approach,

```
def index_(ids, id):
    split_ = ids.split(",")
    if id in split_:
        return split_.index(id)
    else:
        return -1


print(
    df.assign(id = df1.id.astype(str))
        .apply(lambda x: index_(x.ids, x.id), axis=1)
)
```

---

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Really shouldn't need to use `apply` here.  On larger Dataframes it will be incredibly slow. Broadcasted comparison will work just fine.

```
(df["ids"].str.split(",", expand=True) == df["id"][:, None]).idxmax(1)
```

---

```
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
dtype: int64
```

---

***Performance***

```
d = {'ids': {0: '18281483,1658391547',
             1: '1268212,128064430',
             2: '1346542425',
             3: '13591493,13123669,35938208'},
      'id': {0: '18281483', 
             1: '1268212', 
             2: '1346542425',
             3: '13123669'}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000)

%timeit (df["ids"].str.split(",", expand=True) == df["id"][:, None]).idxmax(1)                 
7.51 ms ± 61.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x['ids'].split(',').index(x['id']), axis=1)                         
54.1 ms ± 249 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```